# JavaScript array returning unidentified

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Hi I'm needing some help I'm pretty new to coding I can't seem to get my function to work it keeps returning undefined, any tips would be appreciated. thanks

```
var german = ["eins","zwei","drei","vier","fünf","sechs","sieben","acht","neun","zehn","elf","zwölf","dreizehn","vierzehn","fünfzehn","sechzehn","siebzehn","achtzehn","neunzehn","zwanzig","einundzwanzig","zweiundzwanzig","dreiundzwanzig","vierundzwanzig","fünfundzwanzig","sechsundzwanzig","siebenundzwanzig","achtundzwanzig","neunundzwanzig","dreiβig"];
var french = ["un","duex","trois","quatre","cinq","six","sept","huit","neuf","dix","onze","douze","treize","quatorze","quinze","seize","dix-sept","dix-huit","dix-neuf","vingt","vingt et un","vingt-deux","vingt-trois","vingt-quatre","vingt-cinq","vingt-six","vingt-sept","vingt-huit","vingt-neuf","trente"];

var translatedNumber = translate();


var number = prompt("Please enter a number between 1-30 to be translated");
    if (number > 30 || number < 1) {
        alert("Please enter a number between 1-30")
        exit()
    }
    else if(isNaN(number)){
        alert("Please enter digits")
        exit()
    }


var language = prompt("Translated into what language? French/German");

    if (language == "german" || language == "french"){
    translate();
    } 
    else{
    alert("Only French or German is allowed")
    exit()
    }

function translate(number,language,translatedNumber,french,german){
    if(language == "german"){
        var translatedNumber = german[number - 1];
        }
    
    else if(language == "french"){
        var translatedNumber = french[number - 1];
        }
    return translatedNumber;
}

alert("The translation is " + translatedNumber);
```

Comment: Go through a [tutorial of how to call functions](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions). You’re calling `translate` with no arguments. Why do you assume that `language` inside that function is `"german"` or `"french"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it:

(The problem was you didn't set up your function properly. I changed the translate function variables to lan and num since those are the only two you use in the function. Also I didn't think you needed to define the translatedNumber at the top yet since you have not used it yet) Hope this helps :D.)

```
var german = ["eins","zwei","drei","vier","fünf","sechs","sieben","acht","neun","zehn","elf","zwölf","dreizehn","vierzehn","fünfzehn","sechzehn","siebzehn","achtzehn","neunzehn","zwanzig","einundzwanzig","zweiundzwanzig","dreiundzwanzig","vierundzwanzig","fünfundzwanzig","sechsundzwanzig","siebenundzwanzig","achtundzwanzig","neunundzwanzig","dreiβig"];
var french = ["un","duex","trois","quatre","cinq","six","sept","huit","neuf","dix","onze","douze","treize","quatorze","quinze","seize","dix-sept","dix-huit","dix-neuf","vingt","vingt et un","vingt-deux","vingt-trois","vingt-quatre","vingt-cinq","vingt-six","vingt-sept","vingt-huit","vingt-neuf","trente"];

var translatedNumber;


var number = prompt("Please enter a number between 1-30 to be translated");
    if (number > 30 || number < 1) {
        alert("Please enter a number between 1-30")
        exit()
    }
    else if(isNaN(number)){
        alert("Please enter digits")
        exit()
    }


var language = prompt("Translated into what language? French/German");

    if (language == "german" || language == "french"){
    translate(language, number);
    } 
    else{
    alert("Only French or German is allowed")
    exit()
    }

function translate(lan, num){
    if(lan == "german"){
        translatedNumber = german[num - 1];
        } else if(lan == "french"){
        translatedNumber = french[num - 1];
        }
    return translatedNumber;
}

alert("The translation is " + translatedNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things to note about your code:

1. The `exit` function is not defined.
2. Your `translatedNumber` is a global variable that is modified from within another function. Avoid such globals.
3. You should check whether a variable is a number first before checking whether it is within the required range.

Hope the following is what you are seeking:

```js
const german = ["eins","zwei","drei","vier","fünf","sechs","sieben","acht","neun","zehn","elf","zwölf","dreizehn","vierzehn","fünfzehn","sechzehn","siebzehn","achtzehn","neunzehn","zwanzig","einundzwanzig","zweiundzwanzig","dreiundzwanzig","vierundzwanzig","fünfundzwanzig","sechsundzwanzig","siebenundzwanzig","achtundzwanzig","neunundzwanzig","dreiβig"];
const french = ["un","duex","trois","quatre","cinq","six","sept","huit","neuf","dix","onze","douze","treize","quatorze","quinze","seize","dix-sept","dix-huit","dix-neuf","vingt","vingt et un","vingt-deux","vingt-trois","vingt-quatre","vingt-cinq","vingt-six","vingt-sept","vingt-huit","vingt-neuf","trente"];

try {
  const number = prompt("Please enter a number between 1-30 to be translated");
  if (isNaN(number))
    throw({ message: "Please enter digits"});
  if (number > 30 || number < 1)
    throw({ message: "Please enter a number between 1-30"});

  const language = prompt("Translated into what language? French/German");
  if (language == "german" || language == "french"){
    const translatedNumber = translate(number, language);
    alert("The translation is " + translatedNumber);    
  } 
  else
    throw({ message: "Only French or German is allowed"});
} catch (error) {
  alert(error.message);
}

function translate(number,language){
  return language == "german" ?  german[number - 1] : french[number - 1];
}
```